# Coin collector’s problem with two backtracking steps allowed

Tags: java, python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, pseudocode

So I have the coin collector’s problem where several coins are placed in a cells of a matrix with dimensions n x m. With varying amount of coins on each cell. A man in the upper left cell of the matrix (meaning 0,0) and he has to collect as many coins as possible but he can only move to the cell to the right of him(i,j+1) or down (i+1,j) and the task is to get to cell (n,m) with as many coins as possible.

I know that the solution to this problem can be found by using dynamic programming and
Setting up the recurrence

```
F(0,0) = F(0,0)

F(0,j) = F(0,j) + F(0,j-1) for 1<=j<=m 

F(i,0) = F(i,0) + F(i-1,0) for 1<=i<=n

F(i,j) = F(i,j) + max(F(i-1,j) + F(i,j-1))  for 1<=i<=n, 1<=j<=m
```

And we iterate over all the cells and then we simply get the value that is at F(n,m)

I forgot to mention this but we know how much coins there are in each cell. So we don't need to discover this information by traveling.

However the twist now is, the man is allowed to **backtrack two steps**, these two steps either separately as one step each at two different points or as one big step together at one single point. Meaning at some point along the road, he can either go forward or down and collect the coins on that cell, and then go backwards again. How would I go about modeling this? What’s the right approach to have? I'm not necessarily interested in the code required to make this work as much as I am in what the proper theory or way to go about this is, that said I don't mind reading code in any language.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is anything known about the amount of coins? b.t.w., I assume movement is `right` (not `left`) and `down`

Comment: I just corrected that, thanks for pointing it out, it should indeed be right and not left. As for the coins, we know how much is contained in each cell so this does not need to be discovered.

Comment: I guess the problem with using DP for this is the (implicit) constraint that although you may, by backtracking, visit the same cell more than once, you cannot collect coins on the second or third visit.  That blows up the DP state space astronomically, and it also messes with optimal path algorithms such as Dijkstra's.